# Fixed px Margin Between two Fluid DIVs

Tags: css, html, width, margin, fluid

I'm working on a layout that includes two adjacent fluid-width divs (each width: 50%) inside one container that is 80% of the body width.

I'd like to have a 10px margin between the left and right 50% divs, but I need the whole assembly to fit within the 80% body width container. I understand that reducing the % width of the left and right DIVs will work to give me room for the 10px center margin, but it would also mean the whole left DIV/right DIV/10px margin assembly would often not be 80% of the body width.

Is there a way to recalculate the width of the left and right DIVs so they cumulatively occupy 80% of the body width when there is a fixed 10px margin in between them, no matter what the browser window is resized to? Not sure if this is doable with CSS. If Javascript is the only way to achieve it that's fine, but it would be great if there's some hidden CSS trick I'm missing.

Here's my CSS:

```
#logoplace {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#navcontainer {
height: 30px;
width: 80%;
background-color: white;
margin: 5px auto;
opacity: 0.7;
}

#navcontainer:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

#rowone {
width: 80%;
height: 120px;
background-color: white;
margin: 5px auto;
}

#rowoneone {
width: 50%;
height: 120px;
background-color: green;
margin-right: 5px;
float: left;
}

#rowonetwo {
width: 50%;
height: 120px;
background-color: blue;
margin-left: 5px;
float: right;
}

html, body
{
height: 100%;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="logoplace">
</div>
<div id="navcontainer">
</div>
<div id="rowone">
    <div id="rowoneone">
    </div>
    <div id="rowonetwo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/KX6eR/29/) that shows the result I'm getting. The right-floated DIV is getting pushed down, obviously because I've set both floated DIVs to 50% and then added the fixed margin.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's one way: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KX6eR/30/ (I had to add an extra wrapper, which isn't great...)

Comment: thirtydot, still brilliantly simple - if you don't mind, add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/KX6eR/30/

Add an extra wrapper:

```
<div id="rowone">
    <div id="rowonewrapper">
        <div id="rowoneone"></div>
        <div id="rowonetwo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​
Then reposition your two inner `div`s slightly:

```css
#rowonewrapper {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#rowoneone {
    width: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

#rowonetwo {
    width: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an element to your HTML you can do the following...

```
<div id="rowone">
  <div id="rowonepad">
    <div id="rowoneone">
    </div>
    <div id="rowonetwo">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the following CSS

```
#rowone {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rowonepad {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#rowoneone {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
#rowonetwo {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
```

Or you can use the `box-sizing: border-box;` property, removing the need for a wrapper

```
<div id="rowone">
  <div id="rowoneone">
  </div>
  <div id="rowonetwo">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then the following CSS

```
#rowone {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rowoneone {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#rowonetwo {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution, however I'm worried about browser support - is box-sizing widely supported?

Comment: Paul Irish seems to think it is pretty safe:  http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on browser support you could use the new box-sizing css declaration. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using border-box, first-of-type, and nth-of-type "type" things in your project - this is what I have been doing when we REALLY need fixed gutter widths. border-box is 94% - but CSS3 selectors like :first of type are IE 9 and up. There might be a polyfill? Below is just the key parts, and I don't love using the wrapper - but it works. See the link for a clearer picture. The math gets pretty funky, but you can do it with as many columns as you want.

[http://codepen.io/sheriffderek](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/tCBHi)

HTML

```
<div class="column-w">
  <div class="column main">

    [column01]

  </div>  
</div>

<div class="column-w">
  <div class="column sub">

    [column02]

  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.column-w {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.column-w:first-of-type {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.column-w:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a 2-year-old question, but yeah, it took me a long time untill I learned to use

```
calc(X% [math operand] Xpx)
```

There are cross-browser variants, such as

```
-webkit-calc(...)
```

I don't know of any others.

I love the above solution with the extra wrapper, though. It's a beautiful hack! :D